# Library function to generate URL from an ASP.Net Web API controller?

Tags: c#, url, controller, asp.net-web-api

While writing some acceptance test code against a ASP.Net Web API controller, I hardcoded the URL (minus the domain and port) to be posted against. This makes me uneasy; if the controller or one of its parameters were renamed, my URL would become invalid, but Intellisense/Resharper would not catch it. Is there a method that will generate the appropriate URI for a controller?

**Example**: given a controller that looks something like this:

```
public class FooController : ApiController
{
    ...
    public HttpResponseMessage Get(string bar) { ... }
    public HttpResponseMessage Post(string bar) { ... }
    ...
}
```

Say I write some test code that looks something like this (conceptual):

```
sendPOSTforJSONresponse(baseURL + "api/Foo?bar=" + bar);
...
sendGETforJSONresponse(baseURL + "api/Foo?bar=" + bar);
```

but what I want to do is replace `"api/Foo?bar="` with something like `GenerateURLForController(FooController).withParametersOfMethod(FooController.Get)`. Is there a method like this in the standard ASP.Net Web API libraries? If not, I suppose I can roll my own using reflection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a project that does this: [Hyperlinkr](https://github.com/ploeh/Hyprlinkr).

Syntax is like this:

```
var uri = linker.GetUri<FooController>(r => r.Get(<parameter values go here>));
```